# Создание теста с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery

Задача следующая: сделать тест, так что бы по нажатию кнопки появлялся один вопрос, пользователь выбирал нужные ответы и нажимал ответить, после этого первый вопрос должен пропадать и появляться второй и так далее, до последнего вопроса.

Собственно всё что у меня есть я приложил в примере, выдаёт такую ошибку, не могу понять в чём дело:

> VM123:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
>   Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь!

Демо:

```js
var answercount;
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").show("slow");
  });
  $(".send").click(function() {
    answercount = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('-')[1];
    alert(answercount);
    $('#question-' + answercount).addClass('hidden');
    answercount = answercount * 1 + 1;
    alert(answercount);
    $('#question-' + answercount).addClass('show');

  });
});
```

```css
#panel {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="flip" href="#here">Начать тестирование</a>
<div id="panel">
  <div class="question show" id="question-1">
    <h3>Выберите цитату, которая бы лучшим образом описывала ваше отношение к работе…</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">1. Все, что делаешь, надо делать хорошо, даже если совершаешь безумство. Оноре де Бальзак</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">2. Работай с умом, а не до ночи. Луций Анней Сенека</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">3. Работа отгоняет от нас три великих зла: скуку, порок и нужду. Вольтер</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Мне всегда лучше работается после того, как я послушаю музыку. Иоганн Вольфганг фон Гёте</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Ничего особенно не трудно, если разделить работу на небольшие части. Генри Форд</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">6. Нет никчемной работы, а есть никчемные люди, которых не устроит никакая работа. Айн Рэнд. Атлант расправил плечи</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">7. Самая сильная мотивация - это работать, чтоб потом не работать. Соцсети</label>
    <br>

    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="question hidden" id="question-2">
    <h3> Что в вашей работе вам больше всего нравится делать?</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">1. Общаться с людьми. Это меня вдохновляет</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">2. Заниматься с документами. Мне нравятся спокойные, размеренные задачи</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">3. Разруливать неожиданные ситуации и находить решения. Я чувствую себя суперменом, который спешит на помощь</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Мне нравится быть в курсе всех дел компании. Приятно, что мне доверяют и ценят мое мнение</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Осваивать что-то новое. Люблю разные задачи, это делает работу более интересной</label>
    <br>


    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="question hidden" id="question-3">
    <h3>Вам принесли газету. Какие новости вы пропустите и не станете читать?</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">1. Новости эстрады и звезд</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">2. Финансовые и валютные котировки, бензин, погода</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">3. Новости в политике и обществе</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Новости спорта</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Новости культуры</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">6. Происшествия</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">7. Новости айти и технологий</label>
    <br>

    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).parent()....` В Вашем случаи пытается вернуть`id` параграфа, в котором лежит кнопка (он отсутствует, поэтому ничего не возвращает).

Следует либо убрать параграф, либо использовать [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), например таким образом:

```
answercount = $(this).closest(".question").attr("id").split('-')[1];
```

В этом случаи будут просматриваться все родители на предмет наличия класса `question`.

Ну и думаю лучше использовать [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) для смены класса у следующего вопроса.

Пример  в работе: *(2 вопроса в тесте)*

```js
var answercount;

$("#flip").click(function() {
  $("#panel").show("slow");
});
$(".send").click(function() {
  answercount = $(this).closest(".question").attr("id").split('-')[1];
  console.log(answercount);

  $('#question-' + answercount).addClass('hidden');
  answercount = answercount * 1 + 1;
  console.log(answercount);
  $('#question-' + answercount).toggleClass('hidden');

});
```

```css
#panel {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="flip" href="#here">Начать тестирование</a>
<div id="panel">
  <div class="question show" id="question-1">
    <h3>Выберите цитату, которая бы лучшим образом описывала ваше отношение к работе…</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">1. Все, что делаешь, надо делать хорошо, даже если совершаешь безумство. Оноре де Бальзак</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">2. Работай с умом, а не до ночи. Луций Анней Сенека</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">3. Работа отгоняет от нас три великих зла: скуку, порок и нужду. Вольтер</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Мне всегда лучше работается после того, как я послушаю музыку. Иоганн Вольфганг фон Гёте</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Ничего особенно не трудно, если разделить работу на небольшие части. Генри Форд</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">6. Нет никчемной работы, а есть никчемные люди, которых не устроит никакая работа. Айн Рэнд. Атлант расправил плечи</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">7. Самая сильная мотивация - это работать, чтоб потом не работать. Соцсети</label>
    <br>

    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="question hidden" id="question-2">
    <h3>Вам принесли газету. Какие новости вы пропустите и не станете читать?</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">1. Новости эстрады и звезд</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">2. Финансовые и валютные котировки, бензин, погода</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">3. Новости в политике и обществе</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Новости спорта</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Новости культуры</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">6. Происшествия</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">7. Новости айти и технологий</label>
    <br>

    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Igorevich а если у меня больше чем два вопроса в тесте, 3 например, то почем-то когда нажимаю на начать тестирование, то сразу два вопроса появляются
https://jsfiddle.net/alcheez/jh5e3otx/3/
не знаете из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: у `question-2` стоит класс `show`. По умолчанию выставите всем кроме первого `hidden`, а ` toggleClass` будет удалять этот класс при ответе на предыдущий вопрос.

Comment: @Igorevich ой, блин, точно, спасибо большое Вам за помощь!

Comment: @Igorevich и ещё один, скорее теоретический вопрос, как проще всего сохранять варианты ответов, которые выбрал пользователь (может быть несколько в каждом вопросе), что бы потом, например, вывести его ответы для каждого вопроса?

Comment: Тут вариантов масса, в зависимости от того, что Вам требуется делать с данными. Например можно использовать `localStorage`или просто завести некий массив и в него пушить ответы. Это уже не относится к данному вопросу, если Вам интересно, то задайте новый вопрос (сначала попробовав самостоятельно что-то сделать) и Вам обязательно подскажут, если что-то будет не получаться.

Comment: @Igorevich подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, что бы бы ответ на вопрос был дан в обязательном порядке (и ответ может быть только один, а не как раньше- несколько), я пробовал писать 
 if (!$(':checkbox').is(':checked')){
        alert('ничего не выбрано');
}
но так не работает

Comment: $(".send").click(function () {
          
        if($(this).closest('input:radio:checked').length > 0){
        answercount = $(this).closest(".question").attr("id").split('-')[1];

  

        $('#question-' + answercount).addClass('hidden');
        answercount = answercount * 1 + 1;

        $('#question-' + answercount).addClass('show');
// if (!$(':radio').is(':checked')){
//         alert('ничего не выбрано');
//}
          }
        else{
    alert('Выберите');
 }
    });
так тожне не срабатывает, не знаю как тут добавить что бы нормально отобраджалось

Comment: Взгляните например на такой [вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/jh5e3otx/6/). Так как это обсуждение уже не касается первоначального вопроса, то отметьте этот ответ (если он решил вашу проблему), а последующие вопросы оформляйте отдельными вопросами.

Comment: @Igorevich спасибо Вам большое!